# System stuck on a controller on live instance does not return any thing nor redirect

Tags: magento2, admin-controller

I am duplicating the category tree with products works fine on my system while checking on live instance.

**scenario**

1. Duplicate category and subcategory but not products works fine.
2. Duplicate category with no subcategories but have products more then
   1200 also works fine.
3. Duplicate category and subcategory and their
   respective products not more then 500 works fine.
4. Duplicate category and subcategory and their respective products more then 500 doesn't works fine and stuck on
   the controller giving 404 error instead of redirecting like other
   scenarios.***MAIN ISSUE***

Comment: Id suggest taking a look at your sytem/exception logs also check your max post size

Comment: again it throws the same error with increased max post size dont know why

Comment: Check you have assigned enough to the post_max_size also check the memory_limit you could also look at max_execution_time

Comment: post_max_size 1000M
memory_limit -1
max_execution_time 99999

Comment: Set your live version into developer mode at least that will throw an error if no error is received then check your server logs

Comment: developer mode is already on on live instance 2.3 it throws undefined index error but on live instance 2.2.7 it throws 404 error and funny thing is it complete the full functionality  that i want from it and then throws the error

Comment: have you got any idea/solution?

Comment: Its very hard to determain an isse without any sort of logs or examples please post your system/exception logs so can review them

Comment: let me check it again

Comment: [2019-04-18 09:56:18] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] [].........this is the error in exception log this time

Comment: Are there no more errors as that looks like a simple layout issue

Comment: no there is no more error in exception log

Comment: Anything within system.log

Comment: nothing in system log just this one "Broken reference" that i mentioned above